# magit to honour file-local tab-width variable

Tags: magit

Some of Python files I work on have the following file-local variables:

```
# Local Variables:
# mode: python
# python-indent-offset: 4
# tab-width: 4
# indent-tabs-mode: t
# coding: utf-8
# End:
```

When viewing diffs in `magit` it displays tabs using tab-width 8, rather than the file local variable.

Is there a way to make `magit` honour file-local tab-width variable?

Comment: You want to know how to get magit to automatically read the `tab-width` value from the file-local variables in the underlying file, but I don't know that this makes much sense.  A git diff can include pieces from multiple files, but `tab-width` can only be set for the entire buffer, not individual pieces of it.  Can you clarify what you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 3):

As you say, it appears that you are just seeing the tabs from the git output being expanded using the default Emacs value for `tab-width` (8), so you can set it to your desired value in any magit buffer and see it how you like.

If you want to do this for every magit status buffer, you could do something like this:

```
(defun my-magit-status-mode-hook ()
  (setq tab-width 4))
(add-hook 'magit-status-mode-hook 'my-magit-status-mode-hook)
```